# Calendar project not indenting and spacing correctly Python 3

Tags: python, calendar, newline, indentation, sys

I am currently working on a function that prints a calendar. I'm not using the calendar library.
My code isn't starting a new line when it's supposed to.

```
def year_month_calendar(a,b):
  if b==2:
    if a%400==0:
      m=1
    elif a%4==0 and a%100!=0:
      m=1
    else:
      m=0
  else:
    m=0
  print("Calendar for", month_str[b-1], ",", a)
  print('Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa')
  z = 0 
  y = 0 # y is calculating leap years
  y += a/4
  y -= a/100
  y += a/400
  z += c
  z += 365 * (a-1)
  z += y
  for l in range(months[b]+1):
    sys.stdout.flush()
    if l > 9:
      sys.stdout.write(('   ')*(int(z%7)))
    else:
      sys.stdout.write(('    ')*(int(z%7)))
    print(l, end=' ')
    if (z+l)%7==0:
      print('\n')
```

This is only a part of my code but can you tell me what I did wrong.

Comment: Why don't you show the output and expected output? You have undefined variables `month_str` and `c` please checkout [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: When should it start a new line?

Comment: Just a note `z` is a `float` because `y` is a float because you are using `/` and not `//` (integer division). So `(z+l)%7==0` is unlikely to ever be `True`. A couple of simple diagnostic debug statements would have made this apparent.